# How to change link display for posts to linkedin timeline

Tags: html, linkedin-api, hexo

I recently posted my personal blog on linkedin. However the link only displays my name and does not have any image or details. Here is how it looks:

[image: The link appears at the bottom]

The offending link appears at the bottom of the image and only displays my name and the url What fields do I add or edit to make the link appear with an image and some descriptive text?

The `<head>` of my website looks like this:

```
<head>
   <meta name="author" content="Connor Leech">
   <title>Connor Leech</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
   <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
   <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
   <meta name="description" content="Connor is a Web Developer based near San Francisco specializing in PHP, Javascript, Serverless and Node.js">
   <meta name="keywords" content="laravel, aws, javascript, php, developer, software engineer, web development, software, node.js, serverless, lambda, san francisco, bay area, east bay, vue, vuejs, vue.js, vue 2, laravel 5, amazon web services">
   <meta name="zipcode" content="94501">
   <meta name="city" content="Alameda">
   <meta name="state" content="California">
   <meta name="country" content="United States">
   <meta name="language" content="EN">
   <meta property="og:site_name" content="Connor Leech">
   <!-- Vendor Fonts-->
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="/bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yantramanav" rel="stylesheet">
   <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries--><!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file://--><!--if lt IE 9script(src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js')
      script(src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js')
      -->
   <link rel="alternate" href="/atom.xml" title="config.title" type="application/rss2.xml">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app/main" src="/js/app/main.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app/animations" src="/js/app/animations.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app/nav" src="/js/app/nav.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: this one might help you https://gist.github.com/nunosans/3028849

Comment: you don't have an icon <link rel="icon" href="sample.png" sizes="192x192" type="image/png">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is to set **[OpenGraph protocol](http://ogp.me/)** (`og:`) `<meta>` properties in your `<head>`.

The four required properties are:

- **og:title**
- **og:description**
- **og:url**
- **og:image**

You actually already have one set for your name (`<meta property="og:site_name" content="Connor Leech">`), which is why it comes through. However, you don't actually use any of the other OG information.

Here's a sample utilising all four:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Shared Article Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description of shared article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/my_article.html" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
</head>
```

Don't forget to set the `"og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` prefix on your `<html>`.

Further information on how LinkedIn utilises OpenGraph can be found **[here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you! Facebook also has a handy tool available for this sort of debugging https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/